# Integrate select2 in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 on a form.  But want to use it throughout the application.

I have this part in my application.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    <%= yield :document_ready %>
  });
</script>
```

And this in my view:

```
<% content_for :document_ready do %>
  $("#menu_category_id").select2({minimumResultsForSearch: 10});
<% end %>
```

and this is the actual input in the view:

```
<%= f.input :menu_category_id, :collection => @product.menu.menu_categories, 
  :label_method => :name, :value_method => :id, :label => "Category" %>
```

This works without any problems.  However I don't want to repeat this in all the views and would like to handle that with simple_view.

Best would be that if I use:

```
<%= f.input :menu_category_id, :collection => @product.menu.menu_categories, 
:label_method => :name, :value_method => :id, :label => "Category", 
:select2 => 'minimumResultsForSearch: 10' %>
```

it would automatically put it in the :document_ready part.  So if there are 3 selects on a page it would do it for all of them with all the options that are specified in :select2

Is this possible with custom inputs?  Or any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a custom input or the content_for helpers here. Assign a CSS class to the inputs you want `select2` for, say `with_select2`. Next, assign them a data attribute specifying the `minimumResultsForSearch` value, say `data-minimum-results`. On `document.ready` then loop through all the inputs with class `with_select2` and call `select2` on them with the `minimumResultsForSearch` from the data attribute.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed wouldn't be bad were it that minimumResultsForSearch can change into a lot of different options.  Sometimes you put ajax url's and everything in there so you don't want that in the CSS.

Comment: If you need to specify another value for the select2 method, you just add another data attribute to the input. The CSS class stays the same.

Comment: Aha great, gonna try it out tomorrow.

Comment: Got it, it's called 'Unobtrusive JavaScript' as you can find more on [Rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript)